# Why do the solutions of the Schrödinger equation form a basis for $L^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics

So I want to investigate the kind of convergence the basis function obtained from the solutions to the Schrödinger equation (SE) offer. But before I look at this, I'd like to learn why we say that the solutions of the SE form a basis for the set of square integrable functions $L^2$. Therefore:

Suppose $\psi_n(x)$ solve the time independent SE for all $x \in A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Why is it true that there exist a sequence $\{c_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$  such that for any function $f \in L^2(A)$

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_k \psi_k(x)
$$
for all $x \in A$.

Comment: You might get better answers on the math site.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I wasn't sure they would know quantum mechanics

Comment: How deep down the rabbit hole do you want to go? This is pretty standard material, either from Sturm-Liouville theory or more generally the spectral theorem of functional analysis, but since you haven't said anything about the hamiltonian it's hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304508/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for your interesting comment. You wrote "since you haven't said anything about the hamiltonian it's hard to know what you're looking for". According to Griffiths, the statement should strangely be true for all Hamiltonians, which sounds too remarkable.

Comment: Because you can set any L2 function as initial condition, and every solution is generated by linear combination of energy eigenvectors, when you fix time to the initial time your function will hace a descomposition on them. So, its an L2 basis. My answer is more physical than mathematica...

Comment: A requirement for a Hermitian operator to be an observable is that its eigenvectors form a  complete set.  So, you can write down operators that don't have a complete eigenbasis and they then don't correspond to some physical property that can be measured.

Comment: "All" hamiltonians, with no qualifier? Is your hamiltonian symmetric? Is it self-adjoint? Is it bounded? Is it compact? Does it have a point spectrum, a continuum spectrum, or a mixed spectrum? Does its domain coincide with the full Hilbert space? If not, is its domain dense in the Hilbert space? If you're looking for rigour, you need to answer all of those questions, and they'll impact the kind of answer you get. If you don't care so much, then one solution is to accept that introductory textbooks like Griffiths' sometimes make simplifications to aid in presentation.